# Why my AWS ELB does not work? is currently unable to handle this request,HTTP ERROR 503

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have deployed Jenkins instance(private subnet) behind public ELB load balancer.
when I put my ELB in chrome I got

[image]

I tried nc

```
nc -v tf-lb-20230124070833580900000003-148864631.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com 80
Connection to tf-lb-20230124070833580900000003-148864631.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
```

The same with jenkins subdomain

[image]

I checked records in the hosted zone

```
   {
        "Name": "jenkins.dopsops.tech.",
        "Type": "A",
        "AliasTarget": {
            "HostedZoneId": "Z35SXAOTRQ1X7K",
            "DNSName": "tf-lb-20230124070833580900000003-148864631.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.",
            "EvaluateTargetHealth": true
        }
```

Try curl

```
curl -i jenkins.dopsops.tech
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

What does Back-end server is at capacity mean?
What is wrong with my setup?

Comment: Can you run `curl -i jenkins.dopsops.tech` and check?

Comment: @Marcin added,pls take a look.

Comment: Its something with your misconfigured website, check [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/556621/aws-elb-apache2-503-service-unavailable-back-end-server-is-at-capacity).

Answer (score 0):

Check your security group of the ec2 instance. It should allow the traffic from the ELB.

Comment: I checked this,allows 80 and 443 traffic(HTTP and https)